# How to apply formula in excel through phpexcel by iterate each column?

Tags: php, phpexcel

i want to iterate through each column and apply formula.

for example:

```
'I'.$ab = ('H'.$ab*100)/A34;
```

I want to apply formula like above in I column where $ab is row number.

So how can i do it.

Thanks

Comment: You start by writing a loop and populating the cells (using `setCellValue()`) with the formula in each iteration of the loop.... no magic, just a couple of lines of code

Comment: okie i know that dear but you can see i have to get previous cell and after that i can put the formula

Comment: Why do you need to get the previous cell? Your formula is nothing more than a PHP string that you can build using concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely basic PHP, just a simple iteration, and some string concatenation

```
for ($ab = 2; $ab <= 10; ++$ab) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('I'.$ab, '=(H'.$ab.'*100)/A34');
}
```